# How to print list of previous URL's (not only the previous URL) on every component redirection in angular14

Tags: angular, url, routes, components, angular14

In my current project I want to show the list of previous URLs with some name in angular14. I have seen most of the solutions providing only the immediate previous URL but as per my requirement I need all the previous URLs of the particular module, if any time user wants to go to any of the previous URL he can click on the particular URL and navigate to that particular component.

Lets say, I have a module named Health. The health-component is the parent component that displays all the health records and there are 4 child components for Add health, Edit health, Details health and some xxxxx.
If user navigates to parent component that is "Health" no need to show previous URL as this is the main component of the module. Here, user wants to see the details of any component and clicks on particular health record. It redirects to "Details" component in this page I need show the user "Health" which is previous URL. In Details component I have "Edit" button, if user clicks on it, it will take user to Edit component. There I need to show the user to "Health --> Details" as these two are the previous URLs. Likewise if again I have some xxxx button in Edit component if user clicks on it, it will redirect to that particular component. So now in xxxx component I need to show "Health --> Details --> Edit" as these are the previous URLs.

Hope you have understood the problem. I want to implement this for all modules in my application.

How can I do this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: @MGX thanks for the quick response, I have tried this
this.router.events
                    .pipe(filter((event: RouterEvent) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
                    .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
                        this.previousUrl = this.currentUrl;
                        this.currentUrl = event.urlAfterRedirects;
                        console.log("prev: ", this.previousUrl)
                        console.log("curr: ", this.currentUrl)
                    });

but problem here is, I'm getting only previous URL, but I need all my previous URLs

Comment: So just store them in an array ?

Comment: @MGX but if I store it in an array, the values will be gone while refreshing the page right?

Comment: Then save them on your server or in the local storage ?

Comment: Yes, I can do that but I just want to know that is there any predefined function or feature is there in angular